# PIL IOError: decoder zip not available after built with ZLIB support

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, zlib

I've pointed setup.py towards /lib where my libz.so is.  When I then run `setup.py install`, I get the ZLIB support confirmed:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.2 (default, Feb  8 2013, 11:05:21)
              [GCC 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
*** JPEG support not available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But then, after install, I still get the error:

```
IOError: decoder zip not available
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not running a previous installation? Try to remove *all* PIL installations and eventually check for remaining `egg` files in the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I've managed to fix it by downloading zlib source and building from that.

Comment: @jdborg can you convert that comment into an Answer

Comment: Btw, take a look at 'pil for humans': https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this by downloading the zlib source, building it and pointing the Image build to that.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you did this? Do you mean that you performed a fresh build of PIL and linked it to zlib at compile-time, or do you mean that you linked the existing build of PIL to zlib at run-time?